# Python: multiple writes to different files

Tags: python, file-io

```
import pickle
import time

def save_dict(name, dict_to_save):
    stime = time.time()
    with open(name, 'wb') as output:
        pickle.dump(dict_to_save, output, 1)
    print 'done. (%.3f secs)' % (time.time() - stime)

class SimpleObject(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        return

obj_dict1 = {}
obj_dict2 = {}
obj_dict3 = {}
for i in range(90000):
    if i < 30000:
        obj_dict1[i] = SimpleObject(i)
    elif i < 60000:
        obj_dict2[i] = SimpleObject(i)
    else:
        obj_dict3[i] = SimpleObject(i)

save_dict('zzz.1', obj_dict1)
save_dict('zzz.2', obj_dict2)
save_dict('zzz.3', obj_dict3)
```

OUTPUT:

```
done. (1.997 secs)
done. (2.067 secs)
done. (2.020 secs)
```

I would like to the writes to happen in parallel so i've tried using threads

```
import pickle
import time
import threading

def save_dict(name, dict_to_save):
    stime = time.time()
    with open(name, 'wb') as output:
        pickle.dump(dict_to_save, output, 1)
    print 'done. (%.3f secs)' % (time.time() - stime)

class SimpleObject(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        return

obj_dict1 = {}
obj_dict2 = {}
obj_dict3 = {}
for i in range(90000):
    if i < 30000:
        obj_dict1[i] = SimpleObject(i)
    elif i < 60000:
        obj_dict2[i] = SimpleObject(i)
    else:
        obj_dict3[i] = SimpleObject(i)


names =['zzz.1', 'zzz.2', 'zzz.3']
dicts = [obj_dict1, obj_dict2, obj_dict3]
thrs = [threading.Thread(target=save_dict, args=(info, data)) for (info, data) in zip(names, dicts)]
for thr in thrs:
    thr.start()
for thr in thrs:
    thr.join()
```

OUTPUT:

```
done. (10.761 secs)
done. (11.283 secs)
done. (11.286 secs)
```

but it took more time; I am assuming due to GIL?

I've tried to use multiprocessing but i got:

```
  File "multiwrite.py", line 30, in <module>
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 227, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 84, in __init__
    self._setup_queues()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 131, in _setup_queues
    self._inqueue = SimpleQueue()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 328, in __init__
    self._rlock = Lock()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 117, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 49, in __init__
    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(kind, value, maxvalue)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

so i've tried to just use os.fork() method but I wasnt sucessful at it.

Any suggestion to make the writes done in parallel?

Comment: Even if your writes are done concurrently, they still wouldn't be written in parallel, since the controller on your hard-drive/SSD would serialize the writes again.

Comment: @MartinKonecny i think i dont care if its actually writing in parallel at that level, i just want to minimize the time it took to write to 3 different files at the application level. Are you saying writing it serially is the optimal way to do that?

Comment: Just my 2¢: solving performance problems without having done proper profiling first is a fraught endeavor. Find the bottleneck with tools, they work much better than clairvoyance.

Comment: @9000 not sure why you are assuming that i dont do any profiling and im not aware of my bottlenecks. but okay.

Comment: @ealeon: I didn't mean to be impolite; sorry. But if you did some profiling, I'd expect some of the profiling results be included in the post, as highly relevant. And I mean profiling, not just summary run times.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to write to several files simultaneously, it only makes sense if you spend more time computing the data than writing, or your files are all on different physical devices.

Bots HDDs and SSDs work *much* better with sequential access. Doing interleaved I/O hurts performance (think of constant write head repositioning).

This is the most probable cause. Go with sequential, streamed I/O where possible.

Also, instead of being I/O-bound, your task can be CPU-bound, where Python's threading can only hurt by lock contention.

Your program creates a relatively small amount of data and writes them to files. Chances are your OS first gets the data to the file system cache entirely, and then writes. Most of the time in your code may as well be spent in `pickle` which is CPU-bound and only executes one thread at a time. I've seen this in practice, and it was quite noticeable on complicated object graphs, though your data are simple.

Comment: my objects are actually very complicated and big. serialization is still preferred?

Comment: If your objects are complicated and big, the serialization is CPU-bound. I recently worked on a bug where Django's RAM cache spend hundreds of milliseconds to fetch a cached database result set, with >50% of time spent in `pickle.unpickle`, also effectively serializing access for multiple web server threads.

Comment: if it's cpu-bound, then i should just spawn a process per each pickle write to a file?

Comment: @ealeon: If you can efficiently pass the data to multiple processes, yes.  Of course, if profiling shows that pickling actually consumes most of the time. If you generate the data or pull it from a database, etc, this will help, compared to threads. If you first need to push data to the processes from one location, you'll have to serialize it somehow, probably, which is the problem we're solving. BTW did you try JSON or Cap'n Proto — maybe there will play nicer with your data? This requires the data to be a tree, not a general DAG.